# Curl CURLOPT_UPLOAD AND CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION not working together (libcurl)

Tags: curl, libcurl

I searched online but could not find an answer to this one. Hence posting it here.

In my code, I am uploading a binary stream to a server using CURLOPT_UPLOAD set to true (PUT request) and setting CURLOPT_READFUNCTION and CURLOPT_READDATA and CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE appropriate to send the stream.

The end point url changed recently leading to 301 moved permanently error. I do not want to change code to read the 301 and redirect appropriately because that seems counter intuitive.

Saw that CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION informs curl to redirect automatically. But it is not redirecting as expected. I see reference to POST + FOLLOWLOCATION but not PUT + FOLLOWLOCATION when I googled.

So my question is. Is FOLLOWLOCATION supposed to work with PUT in libcurl properly?
Also if not, can you tell me what alternatives are there to allow automatic redirections ?

Comment: Did you try just replacing `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true)` with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT")` keeping `FOLLOWLOCATION` as you'd do with a `POST`?

Comment: Will try that and see.

Comment: I was not using CURLOPT_PUT. Instead was relying on CURLOPT_UPLOAD to put the binary stream, which was working fine until the redirection. Anyways I added these two. But still not redirected automatically. Still seeing only 301 response as the final response code in the curl debug. => curl_easy_setopt(CurlHandle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); and   curl_easy_setopt(CurlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

Comment: I had to use the suggested new url directly. Looks like redirection does not work with Upload.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem here, but I noticed my files only fails when I try to send an multi-dimensional array AND put my payload into http_build_query function.
Solution: I encode all my payload into just one string and put my files side by side with the rest of payload. So I removed the function http_build_query and sent my array of data.
It works!

It looks like the PHP doesn't send the files when you: put a multidimensional array + files + http_build_query at same time.